# Python, changing axis of 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have the following code:

```
xx = np.arange(len(days[0]))
ys = [i+xx+(i*xx)**2 for i in range(len(days[0]))]
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(ys)))

for d,cc in zip(days[0],colors):

      ax.scatter(t,p,d,color=cc)
```

t and p are lists (time and price) and d is an integer (day). When I run the code the result I get is below :

[image]

The issue is that the axis are wrong. p and d need to be swapped but
when I try to do:

```
ax.scatter(t,d,p)
```

I get an error saying "Arguments xs and ys must be of same size". Is there any way I can just get the axis to be switched since intuitively the plot does not make sense in this configuration.

The reason that the days are iterated over is so that I can have a separate color for each day on the plot.

I tried the solution of iterating through the t and p lists for each day and just plotting individual corresponding t,d,p points, However that is much slower and afterwards the matplotlib plot is unresponsive if you try to move it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting an error message, but can you give a sample of your data? The following code works fine, and produces the type of plot you are asking for.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# Generate some dummy data
time = np.random.rand(100)
price = 120+10*np.random.rand(100)
day = np.random.randint(0,10,100)


# Plot data
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(time, price, day)
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('price')
ax.set_zlabel('day')

ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(time, day, price)
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('day')
ax.set_zlabel('price')

fig.show()
```

[image]

## Edit:

You can set the colour of the points in a scatter plot by passing a list/array. If we plot the second scatter plot using:

```
ax.scatter(time, day, price, c=day)
```

We get:
[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help, I forgot to include an important detail, but I edited the post to add it.  basically in your example day is a list, however in my case since I would like to have different colors set for each day, so i iterate over the list doing it day by day.  @Robbie

Comment: You can colour the points in a scatter plot by passing a list as the colour argument, see my edit. Is this what you want? Also, is your *day* variable a list too?

Comment: There is still an issue since in your example day is a 100 element list , so it matches the size of the price and time. my day list is just a list that goes from 0-12 .

Comment: Basically I have a list with times that has length n and a list for price which is the same length as time (since the price corresponds to time)  and a list with days which is only has 12 elements.

Comment: days are essentially independent of each other

Comment: Yes I understand that, but using a 3D scatter plot does not make sense for that type of data unless each point (i.e. price & time) is associated with a particular day as well

Comment: Here is the solution i came up with that seems to work : days=[day]*len(t)

Comment: and then just do : ax.scatter(t,days,p,color=cc)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help though!